# Camel File Component - Consumer files overwrite

Tags: apache-camel

what happen in Camel File Component - Consumer  , if a file(1) is in process (so by documentation it is locked  : By default the file is locked for the duration of the processing) , and another file(2) with same name is being save (ftp/non ftp action) into the file (1) directory ? will file (2) will overwrite the in process file (1) ?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the file system you are using, and what kind of locking you are using with Apache Camel. But yeah its always a bad thing to override a file, unless you are sure its okay.

And for FTP then there is less guarantee of locking as a FTP client cannot lock a remote FTP server file.

Study the `java.io.File` api on file locks, and also how file locks works on the file system you use.

Comment: I am using NFS on linux. what will happen in every locking option ? I'm using now the changed option , but I can switch to other option.Suppose the file is in process for 1 minute and at that time another file with same name is being writing by camel to that directory. what will happen? what will happen if it is not in process ?

Comment: Ask the computer - give it a try and see what happens